# Parameter passed in url is not captured when in chrome for me(Only non- incognito mode)

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, web, querystringparameter

For my ASP.NET website, we are passing parameters in URL 
e.g.: `www.example.com/?parametername=parametervalue&utm_parameter=value2`

In my code I'm trying to access this using

```
context.Request.Querystring["parametername"]
```

This works fine for firefox(normal and private mode), IE and chrome(only incognito mode).
For normal mode in chrome its not capturing the querystring parameters. Moreover this is happening only to few people while it works for rest of the team even in chrome.
Is there any setting in chrome browser that could have caused this?

Comment: chrome version im using is Google Chrome 43.0.2357.132 (Official Build) m (32-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Incase any one comes across such a problem you can use the app Fiddler. This helps in capturing and showing all detailed information about the url and its cookies set by web clients. 
This helped me in identifying that problem was on my server side and not something that chrome was doing. Hope this helps someone.